# OData can't filter dates

Tags: c#, datetime, odata, dynamics-business-central

Trying to parse datetime into an OData query. Tried a lot of different syntaxes but I keep getting errors, albeit different - still errors. If anyone has an idea what could be wrong in my syntax, the help is appreciated.

Error:

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Syntax error at position 13 in 'Date ge 17-01-2024 00:00:00'."}
```

Code:

```
 DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2024,01,17);
 // Hent Linjer
 var data = context.Kapbehov.AddQueryOption("$filter", "Date ge "+date1);'
```

I tried a lot of variations e.g. datetime before the date, different formats on the date etc.

The table I'm trying to get data from is setup as such;

```
"Starting_Time": "07:00:00",

"Starting_Date_Time": "2024-01-23T07:00:00Z",

"Ending_Time": "08:35:00",

"Ending_Date_Time": "2024-01-23T08:35:00Z",

"Date": "2024-01-23",
```

The table is an OData endpoint from web services in business central - if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself...

even though it is set up as datetime at the Odata endpoint, the query still takes strings as opposed to datetime. Meaning datetime includes the " ' " symbol.

This works;

```
string date1 = "2024-01-17";
string date2 = "2024-01-30";

// Hent Linjer
var data = context.Kapbehov.AddQueryOption("$filter", "Date ge " + date1 + " and Date le " + date2);
```